# How to Move Labels to the Bottom of a Plot in Plotly?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, bar-chart

I'm working on creating a bar chart using Plotly, and I'd like to move the Task_Title labels to the bottom of the plot. Currently, the Task_Title labels are displayed on the right side of the bars. Here's a simplified example of my code and the data I'm using:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Sample data
data = {
    'Date': ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-02', '2023-09-03', '2023-09-04', '2023-09-05'],
    'Task_Title': ['Task A', 'Task B', 'Task A', 'Task C', 'Task B'],
    'Duration (hours)': [4, 5, 3, 6, 4],
}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a bar chart using Plotly
fig = px.bar(df, x='Date', y='Duration (hours)', color='Task_Title', title='Daily Work Duration by Title')

# I want to move the Task_Title labels to the bottom left of the plot.

fig.show()
```

In this example, I'd like to place the Task_Title labels ('Task A', 'Task B', etc.) at the bottom of the plot, instead of having them on the right side of the bars. How can I achieve this using Plotly?

[image]

Comment: Try searching for positioning legends in plotly, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668369/listing-legend-items-horizontally-and-centered-below-a-plot

Comment: The python code adds the following legend setting. `fig.update_layout(legend=dict(yanchor='bottom', xanchor='center', y=-0.45, x=0.5, orientation='h'))`

Comment: Thank you I tried to do both of those but I am still having trouble as the labels are covering the x-axis label `Date`. I can only make the labels go so far down by adjusting the `y` in `update_layout`. I treid adjusting the height and width but I have not seen that to be very reasonable as well

Comment: "fig.update_layout(legend=dict(yanchor='bottom', xanchor='center', y=-0.45, x=0.5, orientation='h'))" provided by r-beginners placed the legend well below "Date" for me on my desktop system.  You may need to try it on a different system.

Comment: `fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=25,b=0,l=0,r=0))` If lowering is the limit, adjust the default upper margin (`t=25`) to suit your environment.